# Why to clear the interrupt flag before the user callback function?

Tags: stm32, interrupts

In a [tutorial](https://simonmartin.ch/resources/stm32/dl/STM32%20Tutorial%2007%20-%20GPIO%20Interrupts%20(EXTI)%20using%20HAL%20(and%20FreeRTOS).pdf), regarding the following IRQ Handler function:

```
void EXTI4_15_IRQHandler(void)
{
 /* USER CODE BEGIN EXTI4_15_IRQn 0 */
 if(__HAL_GPIO_EXTI_GET_FLAG(GPIO_PIN_13)){
 LD2_GPIO_Port -> ODR ^= LD2_Pin; // toggle LD2 LED
 }
 /* USER CODE END EXTI4_15_IRQn 0 */
 HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(GPIO_PIN_13);
 /* USER CODE BEGIN EXTI4_15_IRQn 1 */
 /* USER CODE END EXTI4_15_IRQn 1 */
}
```

This statement is written:

> It is important to place this if statement before clearing the
> interrupt flags.

What is the idea behind this warning?

Comment: You mean in that case toggle will not gonna happen?

Comment: Yes. No toggling will happen as pending interrupt flag is already cleared when user callback executes.

Answer (score 1):

The code runs a piece of custom code before letting the HAL handle the interrupt.

And because the code only toggles a LED if the interrupt flag for pin 13 is pending, it won't be pending any more when HAL code has cleared it.

If HAL executes your user callback, it means the interrupt was pending and cleared to catch the next interrupt before the callback for current interrupt is executed.

New info:

I read the tutorial and it is clear that the interrupts are not handled as per the intention of how they are supposed to be handled by the HAL.

The author is correct that when the interrupt code calls `HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler()` will clear the pending interrupt flags.

But it is a HAL function that is supposed to do that before it calls user defined callback, `HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback()`

Any user code should normally go into user defined callback, unless there are special needs.

So I would just say it is a poor tutorial which tries to show how to use HAL but fails to show how it is supposed to do with HAL.

Bonus points for the author for putting a disclaimer that it may not be the best way of using HAL.